# What towers are good for deflection in Bloon Td5?

Tags: bloons-td-5

What towers are useful to blow balloons back or to make them immovable for a few seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Monkey Apprentice's whirlwind and tempest tornado upgrades blow balloons back.

Many other upgrades have a short stun - Ninja Monkey and Bomb Tower upgrades, to name a few.

Answer (score 6):

There is:

Ice Tower - Freezes Balloons (keep in mind frozen balloos are not popped by sharp things). Its third upgrade on the path slows nearby balloons and its fourth upgrade gives you the ability to freeze all non-moab baloons ln the screen.

Ninja Monkey - On the second path there is distraction to move balloons the other way, a stun bomb and and ability to criplle moabs to half speed.

Glue Gunner - The Glue Gunner shoots blobs of glue that slow down balloons. The first path is about melting the balloons with glue, the second is about getting glue on everything. The 4th upgrade on the second path has an ability to glue everything in the screen.

Monkey Apprentice - The second path has upgrades that allow the tower to use whirlwinds to blow back balloons. If you give this tower whirlwind, it is best positioned at the back.

Bloonchipper - It loops balloons around itself, slightly stalling them

Sniper Monkey - It can slow down moab type balloons with Cripple Moab uprgrade

Bomb Tower - It can stun ballons with its upgrade Bloon Impact

Answer (score 2):

Monkey Apprentice - Whirlwind, Tempest Tornado

Ninja Monkey - Distraction

Sniper Monkey - Cripple MOAB

Ice Tower - Freezes them, obviously.

Hope this helps.